# CentOS 8: Network Card disconnected on boot

Tags: centos, network-interface, networkmanager

I just installed RockStore on a computer (CentOS based) and it is all running fine, but when the system boots, the NIC is disabled.

I run `nmcli device status` and I can see the device is "disconnected".

If I then run `nmcli con up DEVICEID` the ethernet device connects fine, but if I reboot the system, the NIC is disabled again!

How can I force the card to connect automatically on boot?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a comment by [Aaron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/8965/aaron-d-marasco), I have managed to sort this. I had to edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/if-cfg-DEVICEID` and change `ONBOOT=no` to `ONBOOT=yes`.

Now it seems to work fine.

Comment: Or `nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" autoconnect yes`